# Error Installing Rpy2 2.4.2 on Mac OSX with Fink Python 2.7 and 3.4

Tags: pip, osx-mavericks, rpy2, fink

I am using Mac OSX 10.9.4 with

```
gcc -v

Configured with: --prefix=/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.3.0
Thread model: posix
```

And Fink R 3.1.1 (`/sw/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.1/Resources/bin/R`).

The problem is when I do:

```
sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" /sw/bin/pip-py3.4 install rpy2 --upgrade
```

...

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "_rl_basic_word_break_characters", referenced from:

      _EmbeddedR_init in _rinterface.o

  "_rl_completer_word_break_characters", referenced from:

      _EmbeddedR_init in _rinterface.o

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
  Rolling back uninstall of rpy2
Cleaning up...
Command /sw/bin/python2.7 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/tmp/pip_build_root/rpy2/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/tmp/pip-43Xyf6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/tmp/pip_build_root/rpy2
Storing debug log for failure in /Users/alan/.pip/pip.log
```

I got same error with `/sw/bin/pip-py2.7`.

Comment: I stopped using Fink.